# display an image from array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I want to display certain image(i.e badge_id:2)

right now i have the image in array and my code displays all the four image but i want to display only one image.

```
  import React from "react";

 const BADGE = [
 {
  badge_id: 1,
  img : "/assets/mem.png",
 },
{
 badge_id: 2,
 img : "/assets/member-ship.png",
},
{
 badge_id: 3,
 img : "/assets/silver.png",
},
{
 badge_id: 4,
 img : "/assets/gold.png",
},
];

export default class ProductDetails extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  };
}

render() {
 return (
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                {BADGE.map((m) =>(
                  <img src={m.img}/>
                ))}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: If you want to display only one image then don't use `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a **condition** to achieve that like below:

```
{m.badge_id === 2 && <img src={m.img}/>}
```

### Solution

```
<td>
    {BADGE.map((m) =>(
        <>
          {m.badge_id === 2 && <img src={m.img}/>}
        </>     
     ))}
</td>
```

OR if you want to display multiple images then extend this condition

```
{(m.badge_id === 2 || m.badge_id === 3) && <img src={m.img}/>}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could keep it simple and render the image using the index...

```
return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src={BADGE[0].img}/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you always want to render the image at `badge_id: 2` just go with:

```
const BADGE = [{
  badge_id: 1,
  img: "/assets/mem.png",
},
{
  badge_id: 2,
  img: "/assets/member-ship.png",
},
{
  badge_id: 3,
  img: "/assets/silver.png",
},
{
  badge_id: 4,
  img: "/assets/gold.png",
}];
```

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <img src={BADGE[2].img}/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```